# Is it safe to use document.body in an Ionic app?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have no chance to test on an Android/IOS device right now. Is it safe to use

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function (e) {})
```

in an Ionic app? Will it work on mobile device etc.?

(I am new to hybrid apps, sorry if it's a silly question)

Answer (score 2):

I have used event listener once in my ionic app. But I observed that when you attach event listener in one page its get attached to the whole application. So, whenever you click anywhere in the app, the event gets invoked.

Its not a best practice to use document methods in ionic app. It can produce other errors. Try to use inbuilt native ionic features.

Answer (score 0):

First, why you need to add click event to Body. Because this will get trigger a click event when user taps anywhere in the screen. ITs not good practice. Instead if you want to handle click event to a particular Screen. You can handle it in the corresponding component template files.